# The method setMode("showFrame", true) of axWindowsMediaPlayer not work in WMP 12 for Windows 7

Tags: c#, axwindowsmediaplayer

I use axWindowsMediaPlayer control to play video and I use the following method in order to display the current video frame by moving the seek.

axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.setMode("showFrame", true);

This function works fine for Windows XP but when I try to execute my desktop application on Windows 7, not work.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this problem by programming PositionChange event of the axWindowsMEdiaPlayer component with the following instructions:

```
        this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
        this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.pause();
```